# Why is following expression TRUE?

Tags: c, if-statement, operators, inequality

I recently started learning C from *Sams Teach Yourself C In 21 DAYS*, and I can't understand why one expression evaluates to TRUE. It's one of the excersises at the end of the chapter.

```
x = 4
y = 6
z = 2
if(x != y - z)
```

I thought that "-" has higher precedence than "!=". What am I missing? I mean, it's getting late and I've been awake since 5am, so maybe my brain is giving up...

Comment: *expression evaluates to TRUE*. [It doesn't](https://ideone.com/IKpXmE). Either you are misunderstanding the text or it is wrong.

Comment: There are three semicolons and a statement missing from your code fragment.

Comment: "I thought that "-" has higher precedence than "!="." While you're correct in this case, you shouldn't just "think" things in a Stack Overflow question - you should check, and you should demonstrate that you checked, by showing us specifically how you checked.

Comment: I think this question should be deleted.

Comment: did you try to compile and run this code? if you did you would see that it evaluates to `false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression in the if statement

```
if(x != y - z)
```

may be equivalently rewritten using parentheses like

```
if(x != ( y - z ))
```

because the additive operator `-` has a higher priority than the equality operator `!=`.

As actually `x` is equal to the value of the expression `y - z`  then the condition evaluates to the logical false.

So it seems there is a typo in the book.

Comment: I should specify before that it was only one of the theoretical questions at the end of the chapter, and it was answered by the authors. But, true, if I run it would confirm my suspicions. On the other hand, I assumed that the authors' answer is correct, it was lacking explanation though. That's why I asked the question here. And I really appreciate the help 